# Why StateChart is not equally transitioning to two connected state?

Tags: anylogic

The first statechart contains all the population of 1000. In the next state, it transitions into two state. Please see image 1

[image: Image1]

Now when I run the model, it seems like the second state (Want B) absorbs all the population in like 1 or seconds. But the set rate of transition for both WantA and WantB are set to a rate of 0.01 per second. See Image 2 and 3

[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Now when I run the model, within the first couple of seconds all populations shifts to WantB.

[image]
I cant determine what is causing such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the other msg-based transitions into `WantB` trigger as well (impossible to tell from the screenshots) or your model time unit is not aligned (maybe set to `YEAR`s so all agents do transition *seemingly* fast).

Comment: Thanks. I was sending Message "Promote A!" and receiving "PromoteA!". It worked like a charm.